# Threading problem when adding items to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, observablecollection, wcf-data-services

I'm updating an ObservableCollection of a WPF ViewModel in a WCF Data Service asynchronous query callback method:

```
ObservableCollection<Ent2> mymodcoll = new ObservableCollection<Ent2>();
 ...
query.BeginExecute(OnMyQueryComplete, query);
 ...
private void OnMyQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ...
        var repcoll = query.EndExecute(result);

        if (mymodcoll.Any())
        {
            foreach (Ent c in repcoll)
            {
                var myItem = mymodcoll.Where(p => p.EntID == c.EntID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (myItem != null) 
                {
                    myItem.DateAndTime = c.DateAndTime; // here no problems
                    myItem.Description = c.Description;
                     ...
                }
                else
                {
                    mymodcoll.Add(new Ent2 //here I get a runtime error
                    {
                        EntID = c.EntID,
                        Description = c.Description,
                        DateAndTime = c.DateAndTime,
                        ...
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Ent c in repcoll)
            {
                mymodcoll.Add(new Ent2 //here, on initial filling, there's no error
                {
                    EntID = c.EntID,
                    Description = c.Description,
                    DateAndTime = c.DateAndTime,
                    ...
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when a query result collection contains an item which is not present in the target collection and I need to add this item, I get a runtime error: ***The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*** (I pointed out this line of code by a comment)

Nevertheless, if the target collection is empty (on initial filling) all items have been added without any problem. (This part of code I also pointed out by a comment). When an item just needs to update some of its fields, there are no problems as well, the item gets updated ok.

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First case: Here you a modifying an object in the collection, not the collection itself - thus the `CollectionChanged` event isn't fired.

Second case: here you are adding a new element into the collection from a different thread, the `CollectionChanged` event is fired. This event needs to be executed in the UI thread due to data binding.

I encountered that problem several times already, and the solution isn't pretty (if somebody has a better solution, please tell me!). You'll have to derive from `ObservableCollection<T>` and pass it a delegate to the `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` method on the GUI thread's dispatcher.

Example:

```
public class SmartObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public SmartObservableCollection(Action<Action> dispatchingAction = null)
        : base()
    {
        iSuspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
        if (dispatchingAction != null)
            iDispatchingAction = dispatchingAction;
        else
            iDispatchingAction = a => a();
    }

    private bool iSuspendCollectionChangeNotification;
    private Action<Action> iDispatchingAction;

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!iSuspendCollectionChangeNotification)
        {
            using (IDisposable disposeable = this.BlockReentrancy())
            {
                iDispatchingAction(() =>
                {
                    base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void SuspendCollectionChangeNotification()
    {
        iSuspendCollectionChangeNotification = true;
    }
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void ResumeCollectionChangeNotification()
    {
        iSuspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
    }


    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.SuspendCollectionChangeNotification();
        try
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                base.InsertItem(base.Count, i);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.ResumeCollectionChangeNotification();
            var arg = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(arg);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your way, making my target collection of `SmartObservableCollection` type. But now I get the same error in your base class, in `OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)` method, in `base.OnCollectionChanged(e);` line of code. What I could miss?

Comment: You need to supply a delegate to either the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method of the `Dispatcher` associated with the UI thread.

Comment: What is the "this.BlockReentrancy()" method? Is that something you wrote, or something in WPF? It doesn't exist in WP7/Silverlight.

Comment: [BlockReentrancy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654919.aspx). Basically, it prevents changes to the collection while in the using block. Dunno why it isn't in wp7/silverlight.